# How can I enlist an ODBC connection in an XA 2PC transaction?

Tags: jdbc, transactions, odbc, xa, 2phase-commit

Our application uses ODBC to communicate with a database (Both DB2 and Oracle, if it makes a difference), and delegates business logic to Java by way of **JNI** (So it uses Java *and* C).

What I'd like to know is what tools / software / libraries are needed to allow the business logic (Java/JDBC) and the application framework (C/ODBC) to participate in a two-phase commit protocol.

We run on Linux for this project, but generally support Solaris and Windows too, so multiplatform solutions are preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confusing - could you describe your system better? You're saying 'uses ODBC' and then 'java/JDBC'...what language you application implemented with and how it interacts with databases?

If your code is something other than java and uses ODBC then you're asking in the wrong forum, if it is in java then use JDBC and since both Oracle and DB2 supports XA you would need to use XA monitor and it should work.